# Add attachments in a rich text dokument

Tags: domino-appdev-pack

I am currently trying to add an attachment to a rich text field. I try to do this, so that I can replicate the current workflow, in which the user edits the document, selects the rich text field and adds the attachment with the attachment-button. After the document was saved, the user can click the image and view or save it.

Is it currently possible to replicate that workflow with the domino-db or richtext package from the app-dev-pack 1.0.5?

Answer (score 0):

That functionality is not yet supported. You can add attachments to a document, but they won't be linked to a hot spot in the rich text.